# How do crypto-like software display large bytes as a graphic?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

E.g: On apps like Metamask or Myetherwallet, it often displays the user's public address in a graphic, like some randomised drawing. What is this called and how does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably talking about [blockies](https://github.com/ethereum/blockies). They're a specific variant of the more general idea of "identicons," which use a seed of some sort to generate an icon.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the [QR Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)

This isn't native to Crypto or any one language in particular, it's a matrix-based bar code that can be used to store any type of information - typically URLs or text based information. Functionally, it's not much different than the barcode on your box of Frosted Flakes.

There's multiple sites that [generate QR Codes for you](https://www.qr-code-generator.com/), or you can write relatively simple software to [make them for you](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). There's also a few [QR Code API's](http://goqr.me/api/) out there that will generate them on the fly.

MetaMask is pretty clever in that actually uses a table with white/black cells instead of an image.

Looking at my MetaMask, I wonder if you actually meant the [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) which is just a way to interpret a hash as an image.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `ssh-keygen` (the software used by those wallets to generate keys is probably similar, but as pointed out by the other answer, may serve a different purpose), this is called the `randomart` and is used as [an easy way for humans to validate keys](https://superuser.com/questions/22535/what-is-randomart-produced-by-ssh-keygen).